# Image flickering In Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

This Piece of code I am using to refresh a div without complete page refresh. Its working fine in all browsers , except chrome the functionality of auto refresh is working but after given time interval Images of that section is blinking. How to stop The blink in chrome.

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#multicomment").load("refresh.php?id=<?php echo $conversation['id'];?>");
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $("#multicomment").load('refresh.php?id=<?php echo $conversation['id'];?>');
   }, 1000);
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
</script>
```

Desired Output Which I need: I want to create a comment section with user profile Image.If anybody comments on a particular topic That comment will reflect without pressing Ctrl+F5 with commenter's profile pic Like many social networking sites.

Comment: What is your question? What is the context of your question?  What are you trying to accomplish?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: You're looking for a periodical updater.

Comment: This Piece of code I am using to refresh a div without complete page refresh. Its working fine in all browsers , except chrome the functionality of auto refresh is working but after given time interval Images of that section is blinking. How to stop The blink in chrome.

Comment: That script is doing same but On auto refresh image is blinking only in Chrome and after some time it get set to server tmp file so blinking get stop.

Comment: I just Want to stop blinking of image.Which blinks every 1 sec because I have given 1 Sec auto refersh time.

Comment: Scenario: Its a social network tool where user comment on some topic, so all related user get regular posts due to auto refresh script. Put along the comment user profile pic also get populate same like other social networking sites.in my case image of user blinks please help to avoid this in chrome